# cloudflare api translate curl to php curl and send CNAME update

Tags: php, json, curl, cloudflare, cname

This is a question and answer after much research using some info from other responses found on stackoverflow.

How do I convert command-line curl to php:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120}'
```

The above curl is an example from cloudflare's api manual on how to add an A record.  I needed to add numerous CNAMES or subdomains.  Cloudflare does not explain how to modify the above code to create CNAMES.  So I will get that out of the way first:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"type":"CNAME","name":"subdomain.example.com","content":"example.com","ttl":120}'
```

First I changed "type" field to "CNAME".  Next the "name" field is where you put the subdomain / CNAME or in my case the resulting variable from a foreach. Finally under the "content" field you put the domain your new CNAME points to.

What this looks like in php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
                 'X-Auth-Email: user@example.com',
                 'X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41',
                 'Content-Type: application/json',
                  );
$data = array(
              'type' => 'CNAME',
              'name' => 'subdomain.example.com',
              'content' => 'example.com',
              'ttl' => '120',
               );
$json = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The other answers left out the need for "json_encode".  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To translate valid `curl` commands to valid PHP code I recommend this super useful online converter:
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

By using it, your original command line:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120}'
```

Would be automatically converted to:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"type\":\"A\",\"name\":\"example.com\",\"content\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"ttl\":120}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Email: user@example.com';
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```